# Elasticsearch Master node confusion

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

Running elastic search with 2, 3 and 4 nodes.  Configuration is generic recommended to insure the cluster can respond to requests if all but one node goes down.

For 3 and 4 node configurations, I'm seeing some serious issues. There are multiple nodes electing themselves as master.  What's worse, sometimes those master nodes only know about N-1 of the other nodes.

My cluster is named the same in every configuration file, and each node was given a unique name as well.  The query performance is taking a hit because multiple nodes think it's only an N-1 cluster, and it's impossible to guess which node is going to decide to elect itself as a dumber master.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using multicast? Disable that and list your hostnames in "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts".

While you're at it I recommend you check this out https://www.elastic.co/webinars/elasticsearch-pre-flight-checklist/

One thing I'd like to change from the recommendations in the above link is to have dedicated master nodes.